# multiply two column with many to many relationship in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I want to multiply [cube dim] with [QTY shipped]. since both are in different tables with "MANY TO MANY" relationship. so I cannot use related function.
kindly help me with the solution.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can write following measure to calculate product

```
Measure = sumx(ITEM MASTER FILE,  ITEM MASTER FILE[Cube Dim] * sumx(relatedtable(Master Data Sheet), Master Data Sheet[QTY SHIPPED]))
```